# How to access each field value in mongodb data queried using mongoose with mixed type schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have data in database like below. Model is defined like `const Any = new Schema({ any: {} });`. Now if i query `const user = await Any.find({});` and try to `console.log(user.name, user.email)` it gives undefined. If I modify model then it is working perfectly , but I want it to be mixed type. Is there any way to do so, or I have to modify schema.
I'm using mongoose to connect to database.

```
{
  _id: "213337867hgduhg3",
  name: "some name",
  email: "someone@email.com",
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by mixed type ?

Comment: schema defined as `Schema.Types.Mixed`

Comment: maybe because you need an array of mixed types since you clearly have 3 fields in your database, and not one.. const Any = new Schema({[any:{}]}); ... Basically adding square brackets to indicate there's more than one field.

Comment: if I define schema like `new Schema({ name: {type: String}, {email: {type: String}});` it works fine.

Comment: Are you trying to have a schema that fits to every entry of different databases ? Like a *jolly* schema ? Because if so, it's not possible..

Comment: I want it to be without restriction, it should fit whatever data is given. I want to know if this method is supported by mongoose then there must be some way to retrieve data. Otherwise I will change the schema and it will work.

Comment: Maybe this is of help, there are some use-cases aswell https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/schematypes.html

Comment: Create a mongoose.model('any',{any:{}},'Your-Collection-Name') .. See if it works like this, specifying the collection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215124/discussion-between-muhammad-saquib-shaikh-and-ispark).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access each properties of the first you have to use `toObject` method.

Taking your case,  code will be like this.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Any = new mongoose.Schema({});
const AnySchema = mongoose.model("collection', Any);

async function someFunction(){
  const user = await AnySchema.findOne({email: 'someone@gmail.com'}); 
    //or find() for multiple result , 
    //iterate through them to get individual document
  if(user){
     console.log(user);
     console.log('name:' + user.name);
     console.log('name: ' + user.toObject().name);
  }
}
```

Outut will be like :

```
{
  _id: "213337867hgduhg3",
  name: "some name",
  email: "someone@email.com",
  _v: 0
}

name: undefined
name: some name
```

first `user.name` is undefined.
To access each property use javaScript `toObject` method to convert it to javaScript object.